# cronjob : No space left on device

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cron

I have attached a new volume to an EC2 instance. Volume was attached successfully.Below the output of command.

*df -h*

**Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on**
**/dev/xvda1       32G  8.1G   22G  27% /**
**none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup**
**udev            2.0G   12K  2.0G   1% /dev**
**tmpfs           396M  340K  395M   1% /run**
**none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock**
**none            2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /run/shm**
**none            100M     0  100M   0% /run/user**
**overflow        1.0M  1.0M     0 100% /tmp**

When i tried to add new cronjob it shows the error that there is no space left.

*sudo crontab -e*

**/tmp/crontab.jVOoWT/crontab: No space left on device**

Comment: See this: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60731/overflow-tmp-mounted-when-there-is-free-space-on

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your /tmp directory is full, first remove the files from your temp directory by issuing the command below

```
rm -rf /tmp/*
```

Run your crontab again

```
sudo crontab -e
```

Comment: i remove all the content from /tmp directory but it shows the same error. Also the df -h return the same output. It shows /tmp is 100% used.

Comment: finally i was able to edit file after rebooting the system.

Comment: A process was writing to /tmp and still had the file handle open.

Answer (score 6):

Please execute `df -i` may be inode's 100% full Remove unnecessary file from `/var`
run your crontab again

> `crontab -e`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on AWS and ultimately the solution was to boost the capacity of the hard drive. Solved the issue.